# Knockout.js "with" binding conflicts with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am trying to use jQuery Mobile and Knockout.js together in a project and am finding that they seem to conflict in a number of ways. Worst at the moment is that certain click events in jQuery mobile do not seem to fire correctly when inside a `with` binding. e.g. I have a with around a `collapsible-set` and it won't collapse/expand.

I have put an example into jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gregbacchus/VQXsK/

This is obviously a simplified example. In the real case I can't move the `with` inside the `collapsible-set`.

Can this be fixed?

(BTW: using jQuery v1.8.2, jQuery Mobile v1.2.0 and knockoutjs v2.1.0)

Answer (score 1):

Use knockout 2.2.0 or later.

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DmNge/1/ and this announcement http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/10/29/knockout-2-2-0-released/

Particularly the part that says, `"The with, if, and ifnot bindings have been enhanced to preserve their original DOM elements on initial binding, so they are lighter and won’t unnecessarily strip out any special behaviours inserted by third-party libraries. I know a lot of people asked for this."`

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is just a work around, but this seems to work

```
<div data-role="page" id="testPage">
    <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="d" >
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
    <!-- ko with: test -->
            <h4>Test</h4>
            <div>hello world</div>
            <div data-bind="text: hello"></div>
    <!-- /ko -->                
        </div>
    </div>                
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in my real page the collapsible set is nested well within the element that has the 'with' binding. So the with binding cannot be moved to the inside.